# Is my title Software Developer?

Tags: software-industry, india

I joined my first and current company and I am at the verge of leaving due to unexpected internal politics, but all these 16 months I have not been given a confirmation nor an increment in salary. 
The internal communication application has always read that I am a trainee. So my question is, will the company give me my experience certificate as a trainee ? Or a software developer ?

Comment: This should be define in your working-contract. Trainee is a level, not a job description. Beeing trainee in one field usually doesn't worth much for another field.

Comment: What country are you in? India?

Comment: @Sempie In my offer letter it reads software developer. But I am not sure about my relieving letter.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Giving confirmation is a formal acknowledgement that I am a permanent employee at the company, which means I am entitled to all benefits that are usually given to the permanent employees. For example, I am now just given 1 day sick leave per month and no other sort of leave, whereas the permanent employees get casual leave of 15 days a year and few more leaves that totally add up to a month or so - all of which I do not get as I am not a permanent employee.

Comment: @DJClayworth Yes, I am from India. Can you tell me why you are asking that?

Comment: @Rai because every country in the world has different laws and customs when it comes to such things.

Comment: What did your manager say about this?

Comment: @MaskedMan He just said it will be normal formality. No idea what it means as this is my first resignation.

Comment: During my time in Research, when I was able to pick one of several titles, I called myself a Staff Scientist -- because i'd always wanted to be a Scientist when I grew up. (Realistically, I'm an engineer.) My point is that titles, because they differ between companies, matter much less than what you've actually been doing. Put down your title as your employer has it, then describe what that really means when you provide the details.

Comment: @Rai Well, then ask him what it means.

Answer (score 2):

Your title is what the company says your title is. When you are officially handled as a trainee, that will likely be what they will write into your certificate. However, usually a trainee is always specific to a profession, so it will likely read something like "trainee software developer".

When you have good relations with the company and you did much work which goes beyond the usual responsibilities of a trainee you might be able to convince them to write that you worked as a full-fledged software developer, but they are not obligated to do this.

By the way, you often can influence what a company writes into your certificates to a certain degree. A company has nothing to lose by writing what you want, but they can lose by writing something you don't want because it might result in an annoying lawsuit. For that reason most companies are usually cooperative when they are approached by soon-to-be ex employees about what to write into their certificates.

Comment: I hope I get my relieving letter as Software Developer. I am not familiar with the laws and guidelines about software industry in India.